# Can't collect price from a webpage using vba/selenium in headless mode

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping

I've created a vba script in combination with selenium to scrape price `$8.97` from this [webpage](https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/terra-delyssa-tunisian-extra-virgin-olive-oil/6000196167258). The script does fetch the content if I run it in non-headless mode. However, my intention is to grab the content in headless mode. I know I can use their api to fetch the price but the very api gets blocked after 4/5 requests, so I intentionally chose this route.

I've tried with (works in non-headless mode):

```
Sub GrabWalmartContent()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/terra-delyssa-tunisian-extra-virgin-olive-oil/6000196167258"
    Dim driver As Object
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    
'    driver.AddArgument "--headless"
    driver.get Url
    Debug.Print driver.FindElementByCss("span[data-automation='buybox-price']", Timeout:=5000).Text
End Sub
```

> How can I fetch price from a webpage using vba in combination with selenium in headless mode?

Comment: What is the error throw in headless mode ?

Comment: `NoSuchElementError` pointing at debug.print line @cruisepandey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the always fun world of web scraping.  You should always keep one rule in mind:  If your scraper works in headful mode but does not work in headless mode, it is most likely that the site you are scraping is blocking headless browsers.

As a test, I pulled up your page in headless chrome (using puppeteer), and took a screenshot.  The result:

[image: Forbidden Message Screenshot]

So, Walmart doesn't necessarily like headless browsers, and they've taken some steps to detect and block them.  There are LOTS of things site owners can do to detect headless browsers, the simplest one being checking the User-Agent header of the request.

I changed the User-Agent to my current version of desktop chrome:
`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36`, and re-ran the scraper.  The result:

[image: Expected Page]

So since this worked, it looks like Walmart is blocking headless User-Agents, but not much else.  The following code adds just one line to your initial code, and uncomments the headless argument. It will print $8.97 in the immediate window as you expect:

```
Sub GrabWalmartContent()
    Const Url$ = "https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/terra-delyssa-tunisian-extra-virgin-olive-oil/6000196167258"
    Dim driver As Object
    Set driver = CreateObject("Selenium.ChromeDriver")
    driver.AddArgument "--user-agent=""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"""
    driver.AddArgument "--headless"
    driver.get Url
    Debug.Print driver.FindElementByCss("span[data-automation='buybox-price']", Timeout:=5000).Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Yep, right you are @Dimitri. It seems we don't need those extra quotes ***"*** while defining `user-agent`. To be specific, this is what I meant `"--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36"`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait also properly to get the text, even though your css looks good.

Or you could set a timeout on the page loading :

```
driver.Timeouts.PageLoad = 20000
```

and then fetch the price just like the way you are doing.

Comment: There is already a timeout in place in that line which throws that error. However, it seems you suggest me to increase that, right? Okay, I' gonna try now.

Comment: I believe that is for webelement, I am saying for entire page laoding

Comment: Sorry, it failed again even with that `20000` timeout. I tried `driver.AddArgument "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled"`, which most of the cases work when I run any script headlessly, failed here.

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay, try to comply with that now.

Comment: That also failed.